# Out Of Memory Exception when working with large images

Tags: c#, image, out-of-memory

The following line throws an OutOfMemoryException when loading a large image

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filepath);
```

I tried with a 8280x6208 8,76 MB image file and lots of other smaller images, that works fine.

But when I try with a 10328x7760 6,44 MB image file, it throws the OutOfMemoryException.

I also tried opening the file in photoshop and save it with worse quality (1,32 MB), but with the same dimensions, it throws the OutOfMemoryException.

I tried upscaling another smaller image to 10328x7760 and that throws the OutOfMemoryException too.

So I'm pretty sure it's an actual out of memory problem and my question is:

Can I increase the memory somehow?

I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bit with 8GB RAM, Visual Studio 2013 with IIS Express. It's a Web Application project.

EDIT: I don't think it's a format issue as suggested, I tried with a 10000x10000 black image and a 5000x5000 black image. The 10000 throws OOM, the 5000 don't.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: What form? He never mentioned a form...

Comment: OOM with an 1.32mb image on a system with reasonable free resources is likely a file/pixel format issue (as is documented to happen in such cases)

Comment: 10328x7760 is still only 76MB of raw ARGB values. Something else must be up. Can you reduce the problem to a short snippet that you can post here so we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani It's a ASP.NET Web Application project

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy So I guess I should look into changing the pixel format?

Comment: @brian - I tried your code in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.1 with a .jpg of 10000x10000 (size is 1.5 MB) and also with a .png of the same dimensions (398k).  In neither case did the code throw an exception.  Both loaded without problem.  What is your image file format?   I did get the exception, however with a 20000x20000 .png (1.5 MB)

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy it's .jpg

Answer (score 3):

Compile it as "Any CPU" and untick the "Prefer 32-bit" in Visual studio solution build configuration.

It's not that you don't have memory, it's that .NET application runs as 32-bit process by default, and it does not have enough memory.

Comment: I doubt the 76MB that the image takes uncopmressed is causing the application to exceed the ~3.5GB 32-bit limit...

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem! I would never have thought of that... no idea how you arrived at that solution, but I love you for it non the less!

Answer (score 3):

From In the [`Image.FromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) documentation we can read that :

> If the file does not have a valid image format or if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file, this method throws an OutOfMemoryException exception.

You might want to try to use alternative method `Image.FromStream`. You shouldn't get the exception

```
var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
var img = Image.FromStream(fs)
fs.Dispose()
```

Comment: But I tried upscaling another smaller image (that didn't throw the exception before) to 10328x7760 and that throws the oom exception. The format should be the same when I just resize and image in photoshop, right?

Comment: I tried your method, it also throws OOM Exception on var img = Image.FromStream(fs)

Comment: Strange, have you tried to pass another argument like that `var img = Image.FromStream(fs, true)` it means that it applies color correction according to color management information that is embedded in the data stream. Do you get the exception when debugging step by step ? Also when you use `img` after `fs.Dispose()` you can get OOM Ex

Comment: Nope doesn't work, I just tested with a complete black image at 10.000x10.000 and a 5.000x5.000 also complete black image. The one with 10k throws OOM exception the 5k doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it and get back

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to load into a `System.Windows.Controls.Image` object with the following code.

```
            Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream("largeImage.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);               
            JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
            System.Windows.Controls.Image myImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            myImage.Source = bitmapSource;
```

Don't forget to `Dispose` the Stream when you are done with it.